# JOIN two data set on the basis of string matching condition in Pig

Tags: join, apache-pig

I am new in Pig and I have two data sets, "highspender" and "feedback".

Highspender:

```
Price,fname,lname
$50,Jack,Brown
$30,Rovin,Pall
```

Feedback:

```
date,Name,rate
2015-01-02,Jack B Brown,5
2015-01-02,Pall,4
```

Now I have to join these two datasets on the basis of their name. My condition should be `fname` or `lname` of Highspender should match with the Name of feedback. How to join these two datasets? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below script to do the same all you need is to replace the names according to your data

```
highs = LOAD 'highs' using PigStorage(',') as (Price:chararray,fname:chararray,lname:chararray);
feedback = LOAD 'feeds' using PigStorage(',') as (date:chararray,Name:chararray,rate:chararray);
out = JOIN highs BY fname, feedback BY Name;
out1 = JOIN highs BY lname, feedback BY Name;
final_out = UNION out,out1;
```

For further help you can refer this [Pig Reference manual](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28inner%29)

**EDIT**

As per the comment script for joining data with string function is as bellow:

```
highs = LOAD 'highs' using PigStorage(',') as (Price:chararray,fname:chararray,lname:chararray);
feedback = LOAD 'feeds' using PigStorage(',') as (date:chararray,Name:chararray,rate:chararray);
crossout = cross highs, feedback;
final_lname = filter crossout by ( REPLACE (feedback::Name,highs::lname ,'') != feedback::Name);
final_fname = filter crossout by ( REPLACE (feedback::Name,highs::fname ,'') != feedback::Name);
final = UNION final_lname, final_fname;
```

Comment: Hi Vikas i did the same way but when i dump final_out m not any results

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain you need to change the file location and name of the files according to your data placement. To debug more dump data after each step.

Comment: Vikas my doubt is how can u join them by their names ,coz high has fname like Jack and feedback has name like   Jack B Brown, I think we have to do some kind of string matching.

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain we can achieve that by any string functions like Indexof but the result will not be accurate as u'll get two rows for the same row.. The "Jack B Brown" first for Jack and then for Brown. Will that be fine??

Comment: Hi Vikas i thnk this way it will work ,let me try also.Thanks man

Comment: Any idea how to get the first character of a string in Pig :-)

Comment: I got the solution SUBSTRING(string,0,1) :-)